# Has a ring to it

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

I was watching a video where a guys says something that rhymes, and the other guys says:
"I like it. It's got a nice ring to it."

Do we say it when something rhymes?
When I looked up 'has a ring to it,' the meanings I found were- 'to seem or sound like something you have heard or seen before' and 'to sound appealing.'

Comment: Saying "[It has a ring to it](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/has+a+ring+to+it)" is about liking the the way something sounds, not just a rhyme.

Comment: Note, the meaning about "something you have heard or seen before" might be a different idiom, "it rings a bell," with the metaphorical meaning that it signals a memory. You could also say "it has a familiar ring to it," but that's just the same usage as this with a different adjective.

Comment: Can say 'has a nice ring to it' if something rhymes but doesn't sound appealing? I mean would it be contradictory to say "Even though it's got a nice ring to it, I don't really like it that much."